# Basic question about linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

It seems like a simple question but I am finding it very confusing.
Can someone explain the difference between these two matrixes
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},B=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

1. $rank(A)=rank(B)=2$
2. Column Space

   2a. $C(A)\rightarrow$ 2D plane in 3D space

   2b. $C(B)\rightarrow$ 2D plane in 2D space

   How are these two transformation different?

Comment: How many planes are there in a $3$-dimensional space? Which one would you choose for identification? Are you sure everybody would choose the same as you? Also the rank of $C=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&3&2\\2&5&5\end{bmatrix}$ is $2$; would you think that $B$ and $C$ represent the same thing?

Comment: How many planes are there in a 3-dimensional space? INFINITE. Which one would you choose for identification? For a given matrix, I will use gram-schmit to find orthogonal basis and will use them for finding subspace. $B,C$ are different so they don't represent same thing.

Comment: Neither Gram-Schmidt gives a single answer, because it depends on the basis you start from. Asking whether $A$ and $B$ represent the same thing is completely equivalent to asking whether $B$ and $C$ represent the same thing. The answer is, of course, no for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not transformations. These are matrices. Clearly the matrices are different. Each of these matrices can be used to construct a linear transformation. One matrix will give you a linear transformation $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^ 3$ while the other will give a linear transformation $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^ 2$. Clearly these linear transformations cannot be equal. There is much more to a linear transformation than its rank and image.

Comment: Although in case of $A: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^ 3$, but the $y_3=0$ in $Ax=y$. We should say that $A,B$ are different because $Ax=y$ and $Bx=z$ are objects of different spaces. Moreover can you elaborate what you meant by saying  "There is much more to a linear transformation than its rank and image."

Answer (score 0):

They map into different spaces. Here's a trick: multiplying two matrices, one which is $a$ by $b$ and the other $c$ by $d$, looks like $(a\times b)  \cdot (c\times d)$.

In order for multiplication to make sense, the inner numbers have to be the same ($b=c$). The outer numbers give the dimensions of the resulting matrix $a\times d$.

Thus, in the first case, you have $(3\times 3)\cdot (3\times 1)$ mapping into a $3\times 1$ matrix, which lives in $\Bbb R^3$. In the second, the resulting matrix will be $2\times 1$, which lives in $\Bbb R^2$.

Now, they will of course look similar, but they are objects belonging to different spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand how matrix transformation works. you said and i quote that In the first case, you have $(3\times 3)\cdot (3\times 1)$ mapping into a $3\times 1$ matrix, which lives in $\Bbb R^3$. Thats correct. But what is the difference between $Ax=y$ and $Bx=z$ when $y_3=0$......whats good in having a 3rd coordinate that is zero. This point is confusing me.

Comment: @NAASI well it isn't necessarily a good thing and in fact it might be totally useless. It's like if you talk about the line $(x,0)$ in $\Bbb R^2$. It's basically the same thing as $\Bbb R$, but it technically is different. $(3,0)$ is not the same thing as $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on Ittay Weiss' answer which emphasizes that these two matrices represent linear transformation to two different spaces.

This will be crude and non-mathematical but I hope it would convey the meaning.

Take two flights starting from Tokyo. Flight A has New Delhi in India as the destination. Flight B also starts from Tokyo and goes to New Delhi via  Chennai and Mumbai, two other cities in India  Assume all the passengers of Flight B got down at New Delhi in Flight B and no one boarded at Chennai or Mumbai. In one sense they seem to have the same effect, but they should be considered theoretically different.